# PHP Nested for loops

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop

I basically want to scan a load of comments for illegal words and then replace those illegal words with a clean version.

I have two arrays, one array has all the comments to check, the other array has all of the illegal words to look for.

The first for loop gets the comments, the nested for loop then scans the comments for each of the illegal words and replaces them. The thing is though - it doesn't actually seem to work. Could you please advise if it is a problem with my loop structure, or the actual update logic?

```
    $numComments = count($commentsToCheck);
    $numIllegalWords = count($illegalWords);
    for($i = 0; $i <= $numComments; $i++)
    {
        $message = $commentsToCheck[$i]['message'];
        $commentId = $commentsToCheck[$i]['id'];
        //error_log($message.'-'.$commentId);

        for($j = 0; $j <= $numIllegalWords; $j++)
        {
            //Get word to replace with
            $word = $illegalWords[$j]['word'];
            //error_log($word);

            $length = strlen($word);
            $first = substr($word,0);
            $last = substr($word,-1);
            $starLength = $length - 2;
            $replacement = $first.str_repeat('*',$starLength).$last;

            $newMessage = preg_replace('/\b'.$word.'\b/i', $replacement, $message);

            //Update the comment
            $sql = "UPDATE ow_base_comment SET message = $newMessage WHERE id = $commentId LIMIT 1";
            OW::getDbo()->query($sql);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have to say, I can't spot any problems with your code. Do you use a debugger for your PHP? They really help.

Comment: When you say it does not work, what output are you getting and at which stage?

Comment: It just doesn't seem to update the database with the new comments (the cleaned versions). So I was not sure if it was a problem with my loops or the preg_replace, but I'm pretty sure that is fine as well based on an on-line checker.

Comment: you should give us more info on the outout you get. Also, for nested loops I suggest you to use foreach, however it is now important to solve this code and not to suggest an alternative.

Comment: try single quotes  '$newMessage' in your query

Comment: I was told to avoid nested foreach loops, as the pointers get confused? I'll add in some debugging outputs and come back with what I find.

Comment: @vijay4vijju, just tried that, no difference. I am going to add some debug outputs and try to narrow this down.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldnt your query not be what I placed below, since it wont see now the actual variables in the query. It will technincally just update nothing, cause there is no actual variable set.

```
  $sql = "UPDATE ow_base_comment SET message = '".$newMessage."' WHERE id = '".$commentId."' LIMIT 1";
```

It's a common error to forget the quotes within PHP.

Comment: I have tried both ways, and neither seems to update the table.

Comment: You might wanna echo out what is in the &newNessage variable and the $commentId to check if it has actually any input. From there on, work back and see hwere it goes wrong if it doesn't have any input. I can't see anything wrong up to the code as far as I look, but you might wanna check your input before it goes through the loop and after, so if it changed anything.